# Laser printer manual duplex printing

Tags: printer, paper

My printer does not offer automatic duplex printing. With few papers i can try using odd and even pages . But if i am printing ebooks then sometimes if  printer grabs two pages instead of one theni have to print 300 pages again as , the numbering disturbs.

Is there any solution so that printer picks only one page not double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into the same problem.  The solution I had to do was print in smaller page ranges, and when I reinserted the paper to fan the paper so the pages wouldn't stick to each other.  I also monitored the printing so if the pages did jump, I would manually get the pages back on track and just reprint the few bad pages.

Ultimately, I got a printer that duplexes, and it was worth the money for the duplex feature.

Comment: I think you are right. I have spend 300$ for that. Now i again have to spend 350$ just of duplex mode